# Regex pattern to extract one section from JSON request

Tags: java, json, regex, netbeans

My string format is,

```
 {
     "group By": "name",
     "time Period": {
      "from": "2015-12-29",
      "to": "2016-02-29"
     },
     "query String": "[nation]: \"India\" AND [education]: \"be",
     "geography": "NA",
     "offset": 0,
     "limit": 10
 }
```

From the above content I want to extract the `query string` value and need to display it in HTML page.I have tried to do that using Regular expression in java net beans. But I am resulting in errors.
Can you please give me the regex pattern to extract query string from the above JSON ?. The Regular expression I have tried is: `\"((\"|[^"])*)\"";`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't Java support JSON object operations. Using Regex is a bad practice for JSON.

Comment: I strongly advise you to take a look at [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse and use these values from Java the way they were intended.

Comment: Try to use https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try JSON parser instead of regex here. 
org.json library can be used.

Refer : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11450182)

Comment: @UUIIUI This is not a link-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best approach. Try using some JSON parser library. If you still want to use regex, you can use the regex below:

> \"query String\": \"(.*)\"